# Popup in a loop for php

Tags: php, for-loop, popup

I would like to use a popup in for loop to permit to the user different number.

The number of loop will be random.

I try this code but I never get the first value only the second value (in this example, only 2 loop)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<script language="JavaScript">

function win1() {
    window.open("try.php","Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
}
</script>
<?php
for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++){

$_SESSION["j"] = $j;
?>
<p><a href="javascript:win1()" onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;"><b>Open Window Example 1</b></a></p>
<?php
echo $j;
}
?>
```

How can I do to have in the 1st link the 1st value and in the second link the second value?

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand. "I would like to use a popup in for loop to permit to the user different number" - Do you mean that when $j = 1, then win1() should open, when $j=2 win2() should open, when $j = 3 win3() should open etc... ?

Comment: i mean if we have two $j there is 2 link. when open first link we see $_SESSION["j"]=1 and when open second link $_SESSION["j"]=2

Comment: It doesn't work that way really (I will get back to you), but what's the point of storing the sessions?

Comment: in fact the code on the other page i open is more complex so i need this session. in my code everything work expect the fact to get the session for the different value

Answer (score 0):

In your code, session j is set for each iteration. First loop = $_SESSION["j"] is set to 1, second loop $_SESSION["j"] is set to 2 (overwrites the first one).

```
<?php
for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++){
    $_SESSION["j"] = $j;
    ?>
    <p><a href="javascript:win1()" onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;">     <b>Open Window Example 1</b></a></p>
    <?php
    echo $j;
    }
?>
```

You can't send sessions between server-side language php and javascript in that manner. I think that you want to achieve is something like this: (send nr of iteration to the js-function)

```
<?php
for($j = 1; $j <= 2; $j++){
    ?>
    <p><a href="javascript:win1('<?php echo $j;?>')" onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;">     <b>Open Window Example 1</b></a></p>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

And in your js make sure the value of iteration is added as a parameter to the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    function win1(j) {
        window.open("try.php?j=" + j ,"Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
    }
</script>
```

***In the try.php*** you then set the session according to variable j.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["j"] = $_GET['j'];
...
...
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I try it and now when I click on the link the window doesn't appear. But the link get the good variable so might be have a problem with the js function

Comment: Look in your js-console (firebug, chrome) - do you get any errors or warnings?

Comment: yes I have this error: ReferenceError: win1 is not defined 
The code source show this:
<script type="text" language="javascript">    
    function win1(j) {
        window.open("try.php?j=" + j ,"Window1","menubar=no,width=460,height=360,toolbar=no");
    }
</script>

    <p><a href="javascript:win1('1')" onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;">     <b>Open Window Example 1</b></a></p>
        <p><a href="javascript:win1('2')" onMouseOver="self.status='Open A Window'; return true;">     <b>Open Window Example 1</b></a></p>

So maybe the js isn't recognize

Comment: Try to put your javascript-block inside the <head>-block of the html document. (It's where it should be anyway). Change the script-block value of type to text/javascript (I apologize for this, my mistake).